# How to call this PLSQL procedure in Java?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, plsql

I've got this PLSQL procedure:

```
procedure GetContractInfo(RequestID number, ParamNames out TVarcharArray, ParamValues out TVarcharArray,
                         SessionID in IRBiS_Const.TSessionID default null);
```

`TVarcharArray` is:

```
type TVarcharArray is table of varchar2(255) index by binary_integer;
```

I want to call it using Java. This is how I do:

```
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().doWork(new Work() {
                public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                    OracleCallableStatement callableStatement = null;
                    try {
                        callableStatement = (OracleCallableStatement) con
                                .prepareCall("begin PREQUEST.GetContractInfo(?,?,?,?); end;");
                        callableStatement.setInt(1, request_id);
                        callableStatement.setString(4, sessionId);



                        //callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY, "PREQUEST.TVarcharArray");
                        //callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.ARRAY, "PREQUEST.TVarcharArray");

                        callableStatement.registerIndexTableOutParameter(2, 16,
                                OracleTypes.VARCHAR, 0);

                        callableStatement.registerIndexTableOutParameter(3, 16,
                                OracleTypes.VARCHAR, 0);                    
                        callableStatement.execute();

                        System.out.println(callableStatement.getARRAY(2)
                                .getArray() == null); // NullPointer                    
                    } finally {
                        if (callableStatement != null) {
                            callableStatement.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

But `NullPointerException` is all that I've got. What could be wrong?

Comment: show your stack trace..to know where you are getting the ex

Comment: `NullPointerException ` at ?

Comment: Ok, look at the code, pls.

Comment: For `param2` you have is a `TYPE` in procedure, but you set it as `VARCHAR2`.. `getARRAY(2)` already gave you a `NULL` and you attempt to make `getArray()` again

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar, well, I know that. But why null was returned? Did I set something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Set the 2nd and 3rd parameter as `OracleTypes.ARRAY` as below.. For Custom Types

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, 
                                OracleTypes.ARRAY, "PREQUEST.TVARCHARARRAY");

callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3,
                           OracleTypes.ARRAY, "PREQUEST.TVARCHARARRAY");
```

Comment: What is TVarcharArray?

Comment: you have defined it as Oracle Type in top of your question.. What happens exactly is, Oracle create a Array for you with the structure of the type name we specify...

Comment: Do I have to keep it in quotes?

Comment: The method registerIndexTableOutParameter(int, int, int, int) in the type OracleCallableStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, String, int)

Comment: ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - invalid template name: TVARCHARARRAY

Comment: I see in your commented part of your code, having `registerOutParameter` as `ARRAY`.. Invalid template means `TVARCHARARRAY` is not discoverable.. it might be because you don't refer with a SCHEMA prefix.. And I never though you use Hibernate specific solution... And I afraid my answer will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you for efforts anyway